# How do I get the new center point and the centered rotation angle after rotating a polygon around an anchor point?

Tags: typescript, math, geometry, html5-canvas

I have a class that stores vertices for drawing onto an HTML5 canvas. The vertices are relative the the center point (0, 0).

```
x_pos: number
y_pos: number
vertices: [x: number, y: number][]
...
draw(ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D): void {
    let verts = this.getRotatedVertices()
    console.log(this.rotation)
    this.applyStyle(ctx)
    ctx.beginPath()
    for(let i=0; i<verts.length; i++) {
        ctx.lineTo(this.x_pos + verts[i][0], this.y_pos + verts[i][1])
    }
    ctx.closePath()
    ctx.stroke()
    ctx.fill()
}
```

It uses the following function to perform a rotation about an anchor point:

```
getRotatedVertices(angle: number, anchor_x: number, anchor_y: number): [x: number, y: number][] {
    let new_vertices: [x: number, y: number][] = []

    this.vertices.forEach((vert: [x: number, y:number]) => {
        let newX = anchor_x + (vert[0]-anchor_x)*Math.cos(angle) - (vert[1]-anchor_y)*Math.sin(angle)
        let newY = anchor_y + (vert[0]-anchor_x)*Math.sin(angle) + (vert[1]-anchor_y)*Math.cos(angle)
        new_vertices.push([newX, newY])
    })

    return new_vertices
}
```

My problem is that the vertices are meant to be relative to the center, but I still want the ability to rotate based on an anchor outside the object. **What I'd like to calculate is the x,y translation and the centered rotation that would be equivalent to this anchored rotation**. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could try using the [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/transform) method (or [`rotate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Transformations#rotating) and [`translate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Transformations#translating) methods separately).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining a similar rotation function for `x_pos` and `y_pos`, it would be possible to obtain the offset. Then, for the vertices, apply rotation w/o translation. (anchor=center)

```
draw(ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D): void {

    let pos = this.getRotatedPos(angle, anchor_x, anchor_y)

    let verts = this.getRotatedVertices(angle, 0.0, 0.0)
    console.log(this.rotation)
    this.applyStyle(ctx)
    ctx.beginPath()
    for(let i=0; i<verts.length; i++) {
        //ctx.lineTo(this.x_pos + verts[i][0], this.y_pos + verts[i][1])
        ctx.lineTo(pos.x + verts[i][0], pos.y + verts[i][1])
    }

    :
}


getRotatedPos(angle: number, anchor_x: number, anchor_y: number): [x: number, y: number] {
    let newX = anchor_x + (this.x_pos-anchor_x)*Math.cos(angle) - (this.y_pos-anchor_y)*Math.sin(angle)
    let newY = anchor_y + (this.x_pos-anchor_x)*Math.sin(angle) + (this.y_pos-anchor_y)*Math.cos(angle)
    return [newX, newY]
}
```